# Simple interesting problem with numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I say that a number $a$ is digitally contained in a number $b (a \leq  b)$ if there exist integers $m$ and $n$, both less than the number of digits of $a$, such that $\Big\lfloor\frac{b}{10^n}\Big\rfloor \equiv a \mod 10^m$. For example, $3$ is digitally contained in $37$, because $\Big\lfloor\frac{37}{10^1}\Big\rfloor \equiv 3 \mod 10^1$. Similarly, $47$ is contained in $9472$ because $\Big\lfloor\frac{9472}{10^1}\Big\rfloor \equiv 47 \mod 10^2$.

Now the best meaning of digital containment can be put in: $b$ "contains" $a$ when you write it down.

Now, my question is the following: What is the smallest number digitally containing all the digits $1,...,9$? Answer is easy: $123456789$.

Now, if it had to contain $10$ also? The answer would be $1023456789$.

Here's my question: What is the smallest number digitally containing all numbers from $1$ to $20$? I would like an approach, and eventually be able to generalize this for general $k$.

---

Upon request, I'll add a caution about the definition with some counterexamples:

My definition should make it clear that $19$ is not contained in $189$, for example. Similarly, $20$ is not contained in $230$ or $2303$. Thus, an unacceptable answer to the above question is $10203456789$, because none of $11,12,...,19$ are contained in this.

Comment: Might be useful if you could explain why the answer is not simply $10203456789$.

Comment: Okay,I'll edit the question.

Comment: Might be useful if you could explain why the answer is not simply $1011121314151617181920$

Comment: It may be. Why don't you prove that this is the answer? And I can find a smaller number, namely $101112013141516171819$.

Comment: My point is that there doesn't seem to be any special trick here. You need to sort the input numbers by alphabetic order (i.e., like on a file system (e.g., "105.txt" comes before "12.txt")). Then you may be able to get rid of some of the last numbers in the sorted list.

Comment: Special trick or not, I'd like a proved answer for $1,...,20$. It may be trial and error with sorting as you say, but I'd at least like an answer for a few concrete cases so that I can develop an algorithm. Actually, there is a trick, because a very similar question appeared in the IMO a few years  back.

Comment: Might be useful to add a link to that question.

Comment: I think this gets interesting as you go into the twenties and beyond. And for the original question, surely its $10112013141516171819$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of *digital containment* is  not intrinsic. (It depends on base 10 expression of those two  numbers. e.g.in base 2, six = 110 digitally contains two = 10, but in decimal 6 does not contain 2.). So best is to use computer programmer's parlance and use string, substring to define it.

Then it is natural to write a computer program that generates all such strings, and then pass it to another program that sorts them.